# In Flutter, how to wait for non future function to complete?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-pub

In Flutter, Data calculation takes time to compute. how to wait for non-future function to complete?
Local Data manipulation takes time to complete. how to assign it as a future or wait for the local function to complete?

Comment: If your function is *synchronous*, you don't have any choice *but* to wait; execution will not return to the caller until the function completes.  If the function is *asynchronous*, then it *should* return a `Future`. If the function is asynchronous but does not return a `Future`, then it's a fire-and-forget function, and there's no general way for callers to wait for it to complete.  If you're asking how to make a time-consuming, synchronous function asynchronous, it might depend on exactly what you're doing, but in general you'd probably have to do the work in a separate `Isolate`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get it off the UI thread, and on to its own Isolate.  Look in particular at `Isolate.spawn` for running code in a separate thread.